# Why do scientists need to measure extremely small intervals of time?

Tags: time, soft-question, experimental-technique

Why do scientists need to measure extremely small intervals of time? Why is it necessary?

Comment: Who are "we"? Who says that we need to? You should provide some context so people can answer in a meaningful way. For instance, I've never personally needed to measure extremely small intervals of time :)

Comment: I agree with @MariusLadegårdMeyer, but I'll take a guess.  Scientists studying molecular dynamics take data once every femtosecond or so.

Comment: @Marius, we do integration, don't we?

Comment: Is it because the smaller is the time interval better resolution of measurement is possible?

Comment: Some things (including some things that scientists find interesting) happen fast.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It all depends on the phenomena one is studying. If you need to make an analysis about the general pick up of a car engine, i.e. how much time it take to go from 0 to 100 Km/h, one does not need to bother about *femto*-seconds rather seconds will suffice. However, for the time scales involved in atomic transitions or sub-atomic interactions have very short time scales. Hence, there one needs to have faster measuring device to have relevant data set to that phenomena.

One can think of it like Shutter speed of the camera. If you want to capture a moving object then you need a fast shutter speed. The faster the object is, the commensurate shutter speed needed to capture the object in motion. Otherwise, with slow shutter speed and faster body all you get is a hazy picture. This is the closest analogy i could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Our world can be modeled with three spatial dimensions and on time dimension. So, to describe an event correctly in that model, the accurate measurement of time interval is essential. Although, this is easier said than done. Uncertainty relations prohibit exact measurement of time interval.